# Displaying n-greatest in Kibana

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In my elasticsearch backend, I have a index stats with a numerical field and a @name field.

I would like to display a pie chart (or some other panel type) in Kibana where you can list the top N @name where the percentage in the pie represents the percent of the total fields are represented.

For example, in one index, you might have

```
@Name: John
Field: 5

@Name: Robert
Field: 5
```

Then I would have a pie chart with John and Robert both at 50%. Is this possible on Kibana?

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, but are you looking for visual aggregations in kibana? Like [this](https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/)?

Comment: Not quite; basically I want to find the greatest 10 integers in a particular field.

Comment: Afraid while I could do that in ES via ordering + size or scripts, I don't know how to merge that with kibana! I'll keep my eye on this hopefully learn. Best of luck though =)

Answer (score 2):

Yes what you are trying is very much possible in Kibana 4 with simplicity & ease.

If i am able to understand correctly you want to show TOP N results of a specific field in pie chart.

To do so follow the following steps:

1. Clicking on pie chart under visualize tab (Create a new visualization).
2. Selecting a search source - From a new search
3. Go to Split Slices, select aggregation as terms.
4. Then enter the field and select TOP in order & size (denote no of records you want) ex:5 will show TOP 5 records.
5. Click on Apply & the pie chart would be generated :)

PS: Feel free to contact me for any further issue, would be happy to guide :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes; It is possible in Kibana; If we are using Kibana latest version then it would be easy for you to create visualization;  Look for Pie-chart in visualization and then proceed next; Fill the appropriate fields and I hope it is not that tough to understand while filling the fields; It will render the pie chat on clicking the "Green" > button.

Comment: its not a matter of creating the pie chart that is difficult. it is populating the pie chart that I am unsure about.